# React Native Expo install error. ReferenceError: process is not defined at Module.RNiq

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I am trying to install a react native application using expo. I have tried all the updating packages and more from previous answers without any success.
It is however failing and giving me this error on the web interface: `An unexpected error has occurred.`
And on the console, it shows me this error message:

```
ReferenceError: process is not defined
    at Module.RNiq (index-1b0e10d3020a016605d2.js:1:237007)
    at l (webpack-e067438c4cf4ef2ef178.js:1:563)
    at index-1b0e10d3020a016605d2.js:1:457536
    at main-41e61ebd24edb78847da.js:1:19485
    at main-41e61ebd24edb78847da.js:1:19653
ue @ main-41e61ebd24edb78847da.js:1
```

My `package.json` is

```js
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "expo": "~45.0.0",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.3.0",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2",
    "react-native": "0.68.2",
    "react-native-web": "0.17.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kS7JP.png)

Comment: Please share your code, we can't understand anything from the error only

Answer (score 1):

I was using expo-cli version 5.4.10 but on rolling back to expo-cli version 5.4.9 it worked. Find the various npm expo versions [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/expo-cli?activeTab=versions)

Comment: Similar issue for me; failed to start with the same error with 5.6.0, worked fine with 5.4.12.

Comment: Same for me. Update to 5.6.0 did not work. Rollback to 5.4.12 works fine.